# ReactJS - returns empty elements in DOM

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am new to React JS and creating an app which diplays campaigns and their details. I am using Firebase as database.
I managed to display the list of campaigns and its details. When user clicks on each campaing number it links to the preview page of this campaign:

```
<th><Link to={"/Preview/"+cam.id} key={cam.id}>{cam.cnumber}</Link></th>
```

On the Preview page the id in URL is correct and console.log(camp)(After setState) gives object with all the data but it doesn't render the list in a DOM. Anyone can help with this one please?

Console.log(cam) from renderOptions() prints:

```
{id: "L0000000", cnumber: undefined, adnumber: undefined, weekno: undefined, title: undefined, …}
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from './firebase';
import banner from './banner.jpg';
import Header from './Header';
import { key } from "firebase-key";

class Preview extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            camp:[],
        };
        this.renderOptions = this.renderOptions.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const projectId = this.props.params.key;
        var  itemsRef= firebase.database().ref('campaigns/'+ projectId);
        itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            let camp = snapshot.val();
            let newState = [];

            newState.push({
                id:projectId,
                cnumber: projectId.cnumber,
                adnumber:projectId.adnumber,
                weekno:projectId.weekno,
                title:projectId.title,
                brand:projectId.brand,
                advertiser:projectId.advertiser
            });

            this.setState({
                camp:newState
            });
        console.log(camp);
        });
    }

    renderOptions(e) {
        return this.state.camp.map((cam) => {
            console.log(cam);
            return(
                <ul key={cam.id}>
                <li>{cam.cnumber}</li>
                <li>{cam.weekno}</li>
                <li>{cam.adnumber}</li>
                <li>{cam.title}</li>
                <li>{cam.brand}</li>
                <li>{cam.advertiser}</li>
                </ul>
            );
        });
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            <Header />
                {this.renderOptions()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Preview;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `newState.push` at `itemsRef.on('value', ...)`, you seem to be using `projectId` object to fill in the informations. Shouldn't you be using the `camp` object that you parsed through from `snapshot`?

Comment: Thank you so much Kujira. Yes that has solved the problem :)